# List all possible permutations of string with maximum repeated characters

Tags: python

I need to produce all possible 10 character strings made up of the letters 'ABCDE'.  However, strings containing 3 or more consecutive occurrences of the same letter are considered invalid.
Is there a fast way to do so?

My current code is as follows:

```
import itertools as it
import re
def check_pattern(possible_string):
 reg=re.compile(r'(\w).*\1{3,}')
 if reg.match(possible_string):
  return False
 else:
  return True

st='ABCDE'

for x in it.product(st, repeat=10):
 out=''.join(x)
 if check_pattern(out):
  print(out)
```

Is there a more optimized way of doing it?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about your approach, strings containing 3 or more consecutive equal letters are less than 5% of all possible strings.

Comment: Although it may be less than 5% of all possible strings, it still takes a while before anything is generated.  The above starts generating the following:
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAB
AAAAAAAAAC
AAAAAAAAAD
AAAAAAAAAE
AAAAAAAABA
......
so on and so forth.  It would take some time before a valid string is seen.

Comment: what does "it takes a while" mean ... its pretty fast on my machine(1.6s) ... using pandas it actually took over 2s

Answer (score 2):

Your code is buggy, for example this string `AAABAABAAB` shouldn't work, but it does.

Here's a generator that does what you're looking for:

```
def generate(alphabet, length=10, max_repeat=2):
    if length == 0:
        yield ''
        return

    for c in alphabet:
        for gen in generate(alphabet, length - 1, max_repeat):
            if gen[:max_repeat] == c * max_repeat:
                continue
            yield c + gen

for s in generate('ABCDE'):
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not a lot different than your original: generate all the products and only print the ones that don't have repeats. However, it uses `itertools.filterfalse()` with a defined function `has_repeats` to check whether each product has a character repeated more than the allowable number of times:

```py
import itertools as it

def has_repeats(product_str, max_repeat=2):
    """Check if product_str has no character repeated more than some number of times."""
    
    window = []
    for i in product_str:
        if window == []:
            window.append(i)
        elif i == window[-1]:
            window.append(i)
            if len(window) > max_repeat:
                return True
        else:
            window = [i]
            
    return False

def products_no_repeats(input, length=10, max_repeat=2):
    return it.filterfalse(lambda x: has_repeats(x, max_repeat), it.product(input, repeat=length))

input = 'ABCDE'

for p in products_no_repeats(input):
    print(''.join(p))
```

We can compare this to @Francisco's answer by summing up the number of generated strings and timing how long that took in seconds:

```py
import time
t0 = time.time()
def generate(alphabet, length=10, max_repeat=2):
    if length == 0:
        yield ''
        return

    for c in alphabet:
        for gen in generate(alphabet, length - 1, max_repeat):
            if gen[:max_repeat] == c * max_repeat:
                continue
            yield c + gen
            

input = 'ABCDE'
num_generated = sum(1 for _ in generate('ABCDE'))
t1 = time.time()
print(num_generated, t1-t0)
```

Prints: `7348480 19.735414266586304`

The code above, timed:

```py
import itertools as it
import time

t0 = time.time()

def has_repeats(product_str, max_repeat=2):
    """Check if product_str has no character repeated more than some number of times."""
    
    window = []
    for i in product_str:
        if window == []:
            window.append(i)
        elif i == window[-1]:
            window.append(i)
            if len(window) > max_repeat:
                return True
        else:
            window = [i]
            
    return False

def products_no_repeats(input, length=10, max_repeat=2):
    return it.filterfalse(lambda x: has_repeats(x, max_repeat), it.product(input, repeat=length))

input = 'ABCDE'
num_products = sum(1 for _ in products_no_repeats(input))
t1 = time.time()
print(num_products, t1-t0)
```

Prints `7348480 11.044001817703247`